# Order of evaluation in a slice literal

Tags: go

I recently went through Go's "Language Specification" https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation but found the order of evaluation being different from what it is explained in this document.

For example, it says:

```
a := 1
f := func() int { a++; return a }
x := []int{a, f()}            // x may be [1, 2] or [2, 2]: evaluation order between a and f() is not specified
```

Then I tried with this code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for {
        result := evaluate()
        if result == 1 { 
            break
        }   
    }   
}

func evaluate() int {
    a := 1
    f := func() int { a++; return a } 
    x := []int{a, f()}
    fmt.Println(x)
    return x[0]
}
```

I found the value of slice x is always [2,2]. Is there anything I misunderstand?

Comment: Just because it's not specified, doesn't mean the current implementation doesn't pick a single way to evaluate the order.

Comment: @JimB I think the question is why does the function, which is added to the slice second, get evaluated before the first value is added to the slice, when the first value is entered into the array first? It really has nothing to do with the specifications on the golang site- it has to do with how the code operates. EDIT: Though I could be completely misunderstanding- but I'd like to know :\

Comment: As JimB points out, the spec is telling you what the language guarantees you. It's common to see things like this. In reality, the result is usually consistent as long as there is no implementation change (like in a new language version). That being said, there is a reason the spec says what it does and I recommend taking it at face value.

Comment: I think it's vague to say "is not specified" in the document. Because it doesn't clarify WHEN the value of x is [1,2] or [2,2]. Maybe I run it for 1million times and got one for [1,2] or maybe I run the code in a different architect platform for a different result.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Thank you for explaining. :) So it could go in either order- best to test it each time you implement something like this then?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal  It sounds reasonable. Thank you.

Comment: @MikelBitson: no, you don't test it at all. You simply don't write code that depends on unspecified behavior.

Comment: @MikelBitson no, my point is I would not write any code that depends on a particular observed ordering because Google could go and change the code behind that since they haven't specified an order. If they knew that it would not change, then it probably would have been specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order 'not specified' means that it's up to compiler to decide, and it is not guaranteed to be the same over different versions of a compiler/other compilers etc/other machine/other time of day etc.

It does not mean that it has to be different each time or crash (as you may be accustomed to from C, where 'undefined behaviour' usually meant something bad, for example like using a pointer after freeing memory)

Comment: Then, since the compiler for Golang is most likely the official one, then for a certain Golang version and certain platform. The order of evaluation is always "specified"(a certain result).

Comment: @pellucid: there are multiple go implementations (gc, gccgo). Go has an official specification, and there's simply no reason to ever rely on unspecified behavior.

Comment: Even in C, "undefined behavior" does not guarantee a crash. And in C, order of evaluation of subexpressions is usually unspecified, not undefined, so the issue the OP is asking about in Go is equally applicable to C.

Comment: Yes, no crash guarantee, 'usually != always', but relying upon it is a sure way to possible unexpected behaviour in the future

Comment: @pellucid: No, if you add something else to your program, the compiler may optimise the program differently or build the program in a different order, and you can't be surprised if the order of function evaluation changes. Do not EVER depend on this order.

Comment: Call it "implementation defined" and you get close to the meaning they have here."

Also, C has two different kinds of behaviors: Undefined Behavior, Unspecified Behavior, and Implementation Defined behavior. They are different levels of "bad."